# how can I change the coursier cache directory of the bundled sbt in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I've migrated my local coursier cache to another part of my system and changed the `COURSIER_CACHE` system property, as described [in the coursier docs](https://get-coursier.io/docs/cache.html#default-location)

My local installation of SBT works fine with this, via shell as well as via IntelliJ's sbt shell. However, when building my app using IntelliJ's build-in SBT using CTRL+F9, I get the following error:

```
scalac: Scala compiler JARs not found (module 'solipsism'): C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.13.5\scala-library-2.13.5.jar, <etc>
```

with `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache` being the default coursier cache location.

So far, I tried to add the following VM Parameters to the
 Settings > Build Execution Deployment > sbt > VM Parameters
 without success:

```
-Dcoursier.cache=<repo dir>
-Dsbt.coursier.home=<repo dir>
```

as described [in the SBT docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html) and [in the coursier docs again](https://get-coursier.io/docs/cache.html#default-location)

Verifying these settings via IntelliJ's SBT shell using `csrCacheDirectory` shows that they were picked up correctly, but the build error persists.

How can I change the coursier cache directory for the default build?

Using Windows 10, IntelliJ CE 2021.1.1, SBT 1.5.1

Thanks,

Cheers,
Joost Papendorp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause: IntelliJ had somehow retained the links to the old repository in the project structure. This is apparently not fixed by re-importing the project.

Solution: Delete entire Intellij project (not just the modules). Close IDE. Start new project. Re-import modules.

Classy.

Answer (score 0):

https://get-coursier.io/docs/cache#sbtd mentions two options:

1. `-Dsbt.coursier.home` system property, or
2. `COURSIER_CACHE` environment variable